# Prevent JSON.parse from rearranging an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

In my web application I receive a JSON string from the server which I keep in the greetings variable:

```
var greetings = '{"2":"hoi","3":"hi","1":"salam"}'
```

Please notice how the greetings start with the index 2 and the value hoi.
Now I want to parse the JSON and the result is the following:

```
JSON.parse(greetings) // {1: "salam", 2: "hoi", 3: "hi"}
```

The order has changed, it seems like JSON.parse orders the result by key.

Is there a way to keep the order of the original string intact?

Comment: If you need a specific order, then use an array and not an object.

Comment: JSON is an unordered structure

Comment: @Héctor **Objects** are unordered data structures…

Comment: no, you cannot, because iteration is usually in insertation order, but keys which could be read as indices are read first and sorted ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally cannot rely on the order of indices in an object. Use an array of key/value pairs instead.

As you can see the keys are parsed to (numeric) indices, which is why they are ordered that way. You could hack around this by prefixing your keys and then stripping those later:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"i2":"hoi","i3":"hi","i1":"salam"}'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{
   "2":"hoi",
   "3":"hi",
   "1":"salam"
}
```

is not an array, its an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Objects don't have any order. 
If the order is important, you need to switch to an actual [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: W3Schools is wrong... [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You'd probably call that a POJO.

Comment: As of ES6/ES2015 there is an order: [javascript - Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: @Patrick I updated your answer with the correct terminology and better links. Mixing up JSON and objects is a very common mistake (as is calling it "JSON Object", which is wrong). But at least now we know where people get that from...

Comment: @str [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys): 1. integers in ascending order, 2. strings (but not integers) in order of creation, 3. symbols in order of creation - all cases have an order

Comment: @Andreas I read your comment wrong, I assumed you are implying it is insertion order. Sorry ;)